# Can anyone identify this early 90s horror story about a monster using a grapling hook to catch people

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I bought this book in 1993/1994 from a cheap book store.

It was a grisly horror about some "monster" creature that lived on top of buildings in a New York like city.  It would swing a grappling hook and catch people then pull them up to it to (iirc) eat! One victim got skewered through the mouth - ouch. He almost escaped by lifting himself of the hook - but the monster momentarily dropped him before re-pulling on the rope ensuring the victim's demise. Pretty gruesome.

Many of the descriptions of the monster face used the phrase "maw" to describe its mouth.

I don't recall much else about the story - I think its gruesome nature meant I may have abandoned mid read :-\

Comment: Hello Alex. Was this a comic book, or a novel? Do you remember anything else? Like what the cover looked like, for instance? If you do remember additional details, you can [edit] your question to add those in. Also take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to see if anything jogs your memory.

Comment: As a side note, it occurs to me that this is a thinly veiled metaphor for fishing.

Comment: @Alex - Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.